# building pen drive driver

Tags: c, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to build a fully functional pen drive driver. Here is what I have done so far:

```
#include<linux/module.h>
#include<linux/kernel.h>
#include<linux/usb.h>

static int pen_probe(struct usb_interface *interface, const struct usb_device_id *id)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "[*] Anubhav-usb pen drive (%04X:%04X) plugged\n", id->idVendor, id->idProduct);
    return 0;
}

static void pen_disconnect(struct usb_interface *interface)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "[*] Anubhav-usb pen drive removed\n");
}

static struct usb_device_id pen_table[] =
{
    //0951:1643
    { USB_DEVICE(0x0951, 0x1643) },
    {}
};
MODULE_DEVICE_TABLE (usb, pen_table);


//usb driver
static struct usb_driver pen_driver =
{
    .name = "Anubhav-usb stick-driver",
    .id_table = pen_table,
    .probe = pen_probe,
    .disconnect = pen_disconnect,
};

static int __init pen_init(void)
{
    int ret = -1;
    printk(KERN_INFO "[*]Anubhav-usb constructor of driver");
    printk(KERN_INFO "\tRegistering Driver with Kernel");
    ret = usb_register(&pen_driver);
    printk(KERN_INFO "\tRegistration is complete");
    return ret;
}

static void __exit pen_exit(void)
{
    printk(KERN_INFO "[*] Aubhav-usb destructor of driver");
    usb_deregister(&pen_driver);
    printk(KERN_INFO "\tUnregistration complete");
}



module_init(pen_init);
module_exit(pen_exit);

MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
MODULE_AUTHOR("ANUBHAV");
MODULE_DESCRIPTION("USB registration driver");
```

I inserted this module in kernel and the probe function worked. I now want to move further and would like to read (and then write also) data in the pen drive.

For eg. next thing I want is to get the pop up file explorer window showing contents of the pen drive, just like it usually works when pen drive is inserted.

I checked the book "LINUX DEVICE DRIVERS 2 edition" but could not find any chapter for USB drivers.

I also checked the link:
http://www.opensourceforu.com/2011/11/usb-drivers-in-linux-2/
but I am not sure if it is guiding me the right direction.

Links to some useful resources and/or e-books will be helpful.

Comment: Check "Linux Device Drivers, 3rd Ed.". It has a whole chapter about USB drivers.

Comment: But recall that it's a block device what you want to do. After reviewing the USB chapter, you have to read all about block device drivers.

Comment: "get the pop up file explorer window". Kernel driver programming has little to do with this.

Comment: What do you mean under "pen"? USB mass storage? It's already in kernel.

Comment: Pen drive is USB stick. And popup is totally in UI programmung. You dont have to worry abt it

Comment: Besides the books mentioned above, also read the [USB mass storage specifications](http://www.usb.org/developers/docs/devclass_docs/) and the SCSI specifications.